# upright uppercase math letter with Minion and xelatex

Tags: math-mode, xetex, mathspec

just a quick question about Xelatex and Minion Pro. By default, uppercase letters as well as lowercase greek letters in math mode are italics. Can I get them upright by hand?

So far, I am using:

```
\usepackage[MnSymbol]{mathspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Myriad Pro}
\setmathfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){Minion Pro}
```

maybe I should work with something like:

```
\setmathsfont[Set=Greek,Uppercase=Italic,Lowercase=Italic]{Minion Pro}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just break your `\setmainfont` into two lines, and you should have separate control over Greek and Latin. E.g., to get Latin in italics and upright Greek:

```
 \setmathfont(Digits,Latin)[Uppercase=Italic,Lowercase=Italic]{Minion Pro}
 \setmathfont(Greek)[Uppercase=Regular,Lowercase=Regular]{Minion Pro}
```

(Reverse the options if you want upright Latin and italic Greek.)

Or maybe I just didn't understand what you were trying to do.

Comment: perfect. I think I want this : \setmathfont(Digits,Latin,Greek)[Uppercase=Regular,Lowercase=Italic]{Minion Pro}. There is still something unclear. If I define \DeclareMathOperator{\dive}{div} and use it whithin a math mode, the font of "div" is not Minion. Why?

Comment: `\DeclareMathOperator` uses the mathrm alphabet. So you'd need `\setmathrm{Minion Pro}` -- see page 5 of the mathspec documentation.